# Patent on a living hinge

Tags: hinge

I have done some searching and couldn't find a definitive answer. Is there an active patent on a living hinge or is it a common utility without a patent that someone can freely use?

Comment: It's an annoyance, but patents often don't use the common term for things. Living hinges have been around for more than 20 years, so I'm sure the first patent, if there was one, has expired. There may be permutations, so newer patents likely exist.

Comment: Here is a patent from 1987 that shows living hinges. https://encrypted.google.com/patents/US4815608 Perhaps you can look at its citations for earlier art.